# android radiobutton disabled

Tags: android, radio-button

If I create a checkbox view and call setEnabled(false), the checkbox look is grayed but if I create a radiobutton, the view is inactive but it is not grayed. 
Any idea ?

Comment: so what's the question ?

Comment: Why radio buttons aren't grayed when disabled ?

Comment: I agree, they should be. I guess they took a few shortcuts, but it wouldn't have been hard. I guess you could create a bitmap of a 'properly' greyed out radiobutton and then substitute it somehow, but I think that would be complicated due to the different resolution options.
Unless anyone has any other ideas? I'm still a bit new to Android and Java

Answer (score 0):

@Arutha I think you are somewhere wrong, I tried by creating a 1 checkbox and 1 radio button  both are grey at the beginning, when we check the check box is selected it changes to green and it can be unchecked, but the radio button once checked it cannot be unchecked unless we rite a function for that. I believe this will clear your problem, If the answer dose't fit to the question please elaborate the question with the code.

Please have a look in to the link: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-radiobutton-example